# update cascade in self referencing table - best practice?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

It seems that it not  possible to set an update cascade on a self-referencing table.

As a consequence, it is not possible to simply rename a parent node. The only workaround I can see is to create a new entry, and then to re-link all child nodes (and probably data from other tables), and then to delete the old entry.

As this is rather complicated, is there probably a better solution, which I cannot see in the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest (I guess that depends on your specific case) solution would probably be to create a `IDENTITY` primary key and reference/self reference on that instead of the name which is then a simple field.

That will allow you to rename nodes without affecting any dependant nodes, and will make it much less complicated to update the structure while still maintaining foreign key relationships from other tables.

Comment: There must be always a non natural primary key, I agree with you.

Comment: Yes that's right, I already thought of this. Actually, this is a new project and I wanted to go away from id columns, because in a prior project, everything was done with id columns and it lead to big additional affords.

Comment: Well, together with your answer, I will combine two worlds now to one solution: Each node gets a primary key as nvarchar, but self-reference will be done via integers (id) which are unique via unique indexes. 

BTW, a complete other solution would be the use of the hierarchyid, but that's another topic.